# Dependency Injection Structuremap ASP.NET Identity MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using the new ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity framework for authentication.  I've traditionally used StructureMap for dependency injection, but I'm having problems wiring it up to work with the new AccountController.

My AccountController constructors look like this:

```
    public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager<OmpUser>(new UserStore<OmpUser>(new OmpDbContext())))
    {    

    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<OmpUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }
```

My StructureMap config looks like this:

```
public static class IoC {
    public static IContainer Initialize() {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                    {
                        x.Scan(scan =>
                                {
                                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                });

                        //x.Register<IUserStore<OmpUser>>(() =>
                        //    new UserStore<OmpUser>(new OmpDbContext()));

                        x.For<OMPEntities>().HttpContextScoped();

                    });
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
}
```

When I run up the project I get the following error:

> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   AccountController, key ""

Any ideas of how to new up a UserManager object for construction injection?  I've tried searching around but can't find much guidance out there.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add following code to your Container initialize method.

```
x.For<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
.Use<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();

x.For<System.Data.Entity.DbContext>().Use(() => new ApplicationDbContext());
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me for the UserStore, however, I have added the RoleStore as well and I am getting an error saying there is no implicit conversion from RoleStore to IRoleStore. : x.For<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>>().Use<RoleStore<ApplicationRole>>();

Comment: @Greg did you find a fix for the RoleStore issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding [DefaultConstructor] Attribute will work.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    [DefaultConstructor]  //This is the attribute you need to add on the constructor
    public AccountController()
    {
    }
   // Other implementations here..........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@vikram, this worked for me.

```
cfg.For<IRoleStore<IdentityRole,string>>().Use<RoleStore<IdentityRole>>();
```