# StructureMap ActivationException on site load

Tags: asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, structuremap

My site is a mix of MVC and WebAPI.  When I first load the site, it seems my controllers are being constructed before my IOC container is fully loaded.  I get the following error when I first debug the site:

```
 An exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll but was not handled in user code

 Additional information: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type PendingCoursesController, key ""
```

I'm using StructureMap as my container and have pulled down from nuget the packages 'structuremap' and 'StructureMap.MVC4'.  The controller that throws the error is a WebAPI controllers.  If I refresh the page the controller is constructed correctly and everything loads on the page as expected.  It's just the initial load the error is thrown, so my page is missing data.

```
public static class IoC {
    public static IContainer Initialize() {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                    {
                        x.Scan(scan =>
                                {
                                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                });
                    });
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
}

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(App_Start.StructuremapMvc), "Start")]
public static class StructuremapMvc {
    public static void Start() {
        IContainer container = IoC.Initialize();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Added this and it fixed it.  Answer from [Dependency Injection Structuremap ASP.NET Identity MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372594/dependency-injection-structuremap-asp-net-identity-mvc-5)

```
using MVC.CFC.Domain;
using MVC.CFC.Domain.Data;
using MVC5.CFC.Web.Infrastructure;
using MVC5.CFC.Web.Models;
using StructureMap;

namespace MVC5.CFC.Web.DependencyResolution
{
    public static class IoC
    {
        public static IContainer Initialize()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                        {

                            x.Scan(scan =>
                                    {
                                        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                    });
                            x.For<IUserDataSource>().HttpContextScoped().Use<IUserDb>();
                            x.For<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Use<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
                            x.For<System.Data.Entity.DbContext>().Use(() => new ApplicationDbContext());
                        });



            return ObjectFactory.Container;
        }
    }
}
```